# Android studio with gradle, How dependencies transitive?

Tags: android, gradle

in android studio, my app module dependency com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+
and dependency a library module(lib-menu) which also dependency com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+

so,how to write dependencies in app's build.gradle and lib-menu's build.gradle?
and i want to know how dependencies transitive.

the follow is my build.gradle,can it cause some errors?

app's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile project(':lib-menu')
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
}
```

lib-menu's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
}
```

Comment: I am using the similar way and getting errors. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This will not cause any error but you can try using provided dependency

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  provided 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,i think that the app will use library module's support-v4,is it?